# Compiling C++11 code on old machines

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to compile a C++11 project on a bunch of old machines with old kernels. They're running CentOS 6.2, 6.3 Alt Linux 4.1. Others are unknown but similarly old. The machines won't let me install a newer version of GCC. 4.4 is the max they can run, and rewriting the project isn't an option.

I somehow managed to build GCC 4.6 locally on one machine, and used it to compile my project, but I don't want to repeat that on every machine. Is there a painless way to compile or run the code on all the machines?

Comment: Working, but bad solution: Compile the binary static. Then it should run under the other machines without having to install newer gcc runtime libraries there.

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade these old machines to something more modern?

Comment: @bigdaveyl no ( they have some specific hardware and drivers are only available for old kernels.. and so on )

Comment: @jofel, is it possible to link all required staff in the application? solutions from quick googling did not make a magic for me, but if it is possible - i will focus on that direction

Comment: I suggesst downgrade your OS.find a old distro.

Comment: @jofel It's not that easy. Even a static binary is not guaranteed to run on a different machine, there are more factors involved. It might work sometimes, though.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh How does downgrading solve the problem? Old distros do not have C++11 support and newer ones do not ship with the required drivers. (From my own experience I can confirm that this is indeed an issue.)

Comment: doesn your program wwork with gcc3.x ?

Comment: FYI: glibc does not fully support static compilation. At minimum, expect anything involving name-service switch (NSS; `/etc/nsswitch.conf`) to break.

Comment: @user286215 “Is there a painless way to compile or run the code on all the machines?” I'm afraid, the answer is **no**. You may want to add some information to your question why upgrading to a newer distribution (the obvious solution) is not an option.

Comment: @Marco, few reasons here:
Machines are complex HPC clusters with many nodes and many manually installed packets.
System administrators do not want to mess with upgrades, interrupting a normal cluster work for weeks.
Some Infiniband drivers work only with old kernels and forcing a new driver to work is a big problem also.

So it just an environment - i should not have aimed for c++11, but did not expect such problem )

Comment: @user286215 how about compiling the *compiler* statically? Then you can deploy it on "almost" anything and use that for compiling "natively".

Comment: It's rather surprising that Microsoft supports C++14 for Windows XP from 2001 (MSVC2015 still has XP redistributable) but CentOS 6.3 (2012) doesn't support C++11. 14 years of backwards support versus lack of support for current standards. Sure, in theoretical sense todays GCC supports C++14 better, but the executables it builds just won't run anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way would be to compile the new version of gcc for all of the machines. You can do this with a script ([lfs](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/) does this). You should be "safe" copying, pasting, and then running the script from a temp account via ssh.

You could also try and update your [repos](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) to have Centos install them for you. Centos might try to upgrade your entire system though.

Also, are you using `-std=c++11`? If so, you might want to try `-std=c++0x`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is still actual for me and i've found a nice solution for CentOS - Devtoolset https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-3/

It provides a current versions of GCC and some other tools for RHEL/CentOS 6/7.

Comment: Be careful, some third party repositories are reported to break the system badly.